# Save a matrix the way it is displayed in the command window

Tags: matlab, printf

I would like to store data in a text file formatted exactly the way it is displayed in the command Window. For example,

```
>> A = 20*randn(4,4)
A =
   -1.0984   25.0050  -13.0311  -38.9769
   18.2225   18.5958   23.8420   20.4100
   11.8917    4.7953  -32.2366   17.2343
    7.0040  -13.8072   -0.4892    0.0232
```

Now I want to store this matrix in a txt file with the same format. If I save this matrix, the output looks like (i.e. the editor is notepad++ )

```
-1.0984,25.005,-13.031,-38.977
18.223,18.596,23.842,20.41
11.892,4.7953,-32.237,17.234
7.004,-13.807,-0.48924,0.023242
```

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to save output *exactly* as displayed, you can use `diary`:

```
% Save output to this file.
diary('file.txt')

A = 20 * randn(4, 4)

% Stop saving output.
diary
```

If you want to save just the matrix, without other output from your script, then you can use `dlmwrite` with tab `\t` delimiters and a format of your choice, for example:

```
dlmwrite('file.txt', A, 'delimiter', '\t', 'precision', '%.6f')
```

Comment: I was going to suggest `diary` too. Simple and effective!